# MySQL Case When with 2 Condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple case like here, anyone can help?
I have two table here COMPLAINT and HANDLING now i want to select from those table with 2 condition where in HANDLING table is null, and date from COMPLAINT is more than 5 days from sysdate.
If I use SQL code like this, it will be error :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'CASE WHEN B.CID IS NULL AND (SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL)-
>   A.`SUBMIT_DATE` > 5 TH' at line 2

```
SELECT * FROM complaint a LEFT JOIN handling b ON a.cid=b.cid
CASE 
WHEN B.CID IS NULL AND (SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL)- A.`SUBMIT_DATE` > 5 
THEN 'OVER'
ELSE 'CLEAR'
END
```

Comment: You miss an operator before case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case statement you have added is in the wrong place and you can not use it in the joining clause as you are doing.

However if you want select something using case when then it must be in the select clause something as

```
select
*, 
case 
 when b.cid is null and datediff(curdate(),a.SUBMIT_DATE) > 5 then 'OVER'
 else 'CLEAR'
end as `some_col_name`
from complaint a LEFT JOIN handling b ON a.cid=b.cid
```

Comment: datediff(curdate(),a.SUBMIT_DATE) > 5 , 
is this for count that SUBMIT_DATE is more than 5 days after sysdate?
why not like datediff(curdate() - a.SUBMIT_DATE) > 5

Comment: oh no you r right :) this code (curdate(),a.SUBMIT_DATE) is for calculate different date from two , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Case statement must be in select and not after join as below :

```
SELECT *,
CASE 
WHEN B.CID IS NULL AND datediff(curdate(), a.SUBMIT_DATE) > 5 
THEN 'OVER'
ELSE 'CLEAR'
END AS 'YOUR_COL'
FROM complaint a LEFT JOIN handling b ON a.cid=b.cid
```

Comment: if i use that , then error like this :

#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'datediff'

Comment: `A.SUBMIT_DATE` to `a.submit_date` please change

Comment: Please refer updated answer. `datediff()` parameter are changed @DelindaDyta